# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - cifs mount not working. cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2

Tags: server, 20.04, mount, raspberrypi, cifs

Ubuntu Server 20.04 freshly installed on Raspberry Pi 4 and installed `cifs-utils`.

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.5/SharedDirectory /home/ubuntu/windowshare -o user=myusername,password=mypass
```

***The above command for mounting the windows shared directory works perfectly on Raspberry OS.***

Trying to do the same with Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on Raspberry Pi 4, it always throws the following error no matter what changes we do

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

**dmesg**

```
[  820.858461] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.5/raspberry-shared
[  831.210444] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[  831.217074] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[  845.175971] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.5/raspberry-shared
[  855.530623] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[  855.537245] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[  975.632052] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.5/raspberry-shared
[  985.835320] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[  985.841947] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[  998.518298] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.5/raspberry-shared
[ 1008.875451] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1008.882082] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Tried the following options after reading some posts and articles but no luck:

1. Disabling ipv6
2. vers=1.0 (also tried 2.0, 3.0)
3. noauto,x-systemd.automount

EDIT: Also tried enabling following services

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online

sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service

sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Windows Firewall Defender was blocking it.

Had to allow @netlogon.dll in Allowed apps in Firewall Settings.

[image]